# How to solve error index out of bounds for axis 0?

Tags: python, for-loop, matplotlib

There are multiple polygons for which I want to change the color and width of a specific edge. There is no problem with polygon initializing (Fig.1), but when I want to change the color and width of one edge of polygons in the for-loop (Fig.2 ) it raised error

```
File "C:\Users\Initi__BC_1024_E2.py", line 41, in <module>  
    vertex[4,i,0,:] = one_coord[j][-1][:]  

IndexError: index 4 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 4'
```

Fig 1. Preliminary polygon(Input)

[image: The preliminary polygon]

Fig 2. Final Polygon (output)

[image: Final Polygon (output)]

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pixels = 600
my_dpi = 100
num_geo=4

one_coord = np.array([[[-150, -200], [300, -200], [300, 0], [150, 200], [-150, 200]],
                  [[-300, -200], [200, -300], [200, -50], [200, 300], [-150, 200]],
                  [[-140, -230], [350, -260], [350, 0], [140, 200], [-180, 220]],
                  [[-180, -240], [370, -270], [370, 0], [170, 200], [-190, 230]]])

for i in range(4):
    geo =one_coord[i, :, :]
    print(one_coord[i])
    fig = plt.figure(num_geo, figsize=(pixels/my_dpi, pixels/my_dpi), 
                     facecolor='k', dpi=my_dpi)  
    plt.axes([0,0,1,1])
    rectangle = plt.Rectangle((-300, -300), 600, 600, fc='k')
    plt.gca().add_patch(rectangle)
    polygon = plt.Polygon(one_coord[i],color='w')
    plt.gca().add_patch(polygon)
    plt.axis('off')
    plt.axis([-300,300,-300,300])
    plt.close()
    vertex_number = 5

vertex = np.zeros((4,vertex_number,2, 2))

for j in range(num_geo):
    one_coord[j]

for k in range(vertex_number-1):   #rang(4), (0,1,2,3)
    vertex[j] = one_coord[j][k:k+2]  #(0:2) to (3:5)
    vertex[j,4,0,:] = one_coord[j][-1][:]
    vertex[j,4,1,:] = one_coord[j][0][:]

    plt.plot( vertex[j,:,0], vertex[j,:,1], linewidth=5, color='r')

    plt.savefig('figureBc/%d.jpg' % i, dpi=my_dpi)
    plt.close()
```

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! Please [edit] your question to include the full error traceback. Based on what you provided, you are trying to index into an array with only 4 elements (zero indexed means the indices are 0,1,2,3) with an index of 4, which would be the fifth element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```py
vertex = np.zeros((4, vertex_number, 2, 2))
```

creates a numpy array with shape `(4,vertex_number,2,2)`. Since python indexes start from zero that means the zeroth axis (axis 0 in the error traceback) has indexes `0, 1, 2, 3`, so

```py
vertex[4,i,0,:]
```

Is trying to access index `4` on the first axis - which does not exist. For every axis the index must always be less than the `size` (exclusive).

Comment: Thanks. The error has fixed but still I can't make that red line on left edge like fig.2. I know there is a problem in my for-loop but don't no where.

Comment: @Hamed Since this answer resolved the issue in this question and you’ve opened a [new question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59915009/10659910), you should [accept](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) this answer so the question is marked as such for future users.