# How to change color of particular edge for polygon in python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, polygon

There is a polygon and I am wondering how can I change color of particular edge of it like figure below.

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np


## -----------------------Initialize Geometry----------------------- 
pixels = 600
my_dpi = 100

coord = [[-150,-200],[300,-200],[300,0],[150,200],[-150,200]]


fig = plt.figure(figsize=( pixels/my_dpi,  pixels/my_dpi), dpi=my_dpi)  

plt.axes([0,0,1,1])

rectangle = plt.Rectangle((-300, -300), 600, 600, fc='k')
plt.gca().add_patch(rectangle)
polygon = plt.Polygon(coord,fc='w')
plt.gca().add_patch(polygon)
plt.axis('off')
plt.axis([-300,300,-300,300])

plt.savefig('figure1/5.jpg',dpi=my_dpi)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this would be to simply plot a line between the two relevant vertices of the polygon, i.e.

```py
plt.plot([coords[0,0], coords[-1,0]], [coords[0,1], coords[-1,1]], color='r', lw=5)
```

Would give you

[image]

Although I recommend adding a border to the polygon with the same width as this line of the same color as the facecolor:

```py
polygon = plt.Polygon(coord,fc='w',ec='w',lw=5)
```

As a way to make the red line appear flush. You can change which edge is colored you simply change the indices of `coords[i,j]` in `plt.plot()` and as long as the indices are adjacent (with wrapping - so last index and first index are adjacent) the line drawn will be an edge and not a diagonal.

Also note you can shorten the plotting command by using slices or a helper function but I have neglected this for the sake of being explicit.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, it worked but how your red line length is equal to the polygon edge but mine is bigger?

Comment: @Hamed That is due to setting a border for the polygon as well, with the same width as the plotted line and the same color as the polygon facecolor

Comment: Nice. When we increase the line width for instance to 5, the line width will extend to out of polygon, which is some cases that polygon has the same border as black rectangle it's not working and the line width remains 1. Is it a way to increase the line width in which the increasing go inside the polygon not the outside?

Comment: @Hamed I'm not certain I understand what you mean: can you give me a link to an image where the issue is happening?

Comment: in the figure you can see that the left edge of white pentagon and black rectangle are same so the line width is 1 instead of 4.  https://i.stack.imgur.com/gxvwn.png

Comment: @Hamed If you increase the line width further (i.e. `lw=8`) does it resolve the issue?

Comment: No, it doesn't. However, lw=8 is too much for the shape.